# How mandatory do 403(b) plans have to be before they are no longer considered elective?

Tags: united-states, retirement-plan, 403b

From [the 403(b) documentation](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p571/ch01.html):

> The following types of contributions can be made to 403(b) accounts.
>
> **Elective deferrals** . These are contributions made under a salary
>   reduction agreement. This agreement allows your employer to withhold
>   money from your paycheck to be contributed directly into a 403(b)
>   account for your benefit. Except for Roth contributions, you do not
>   pay income tax on these contributions until you withdraw them from the
>   account. If your contributions are Roth contributions, you pay taxes
>   on your contributions but any qualified distributions from your Roth
>   account are tax free.
>
> **Nonelective contributions** . These are employer contributions that are
>   not made under a salary reduction agreement. Nonelective contributions
>   include matching contributions, discretionary contributions, and
>   mandatory contributions made by your employer. You do not pay income
>   tax on these contributions until you withdraw them from the account.

If one has a retirement plan at work that requires contributions, is this sufficient to count as "nonelective contributions" - is there further clarity somewhere on what the definition of "mandatory contribution" is?

My assumption is an employer forcing employees to pick a retirement plan (one option being a 403b) and requiring a minimum contribution rate would be considered a "mandatory contribution" but I am not able to find much additional information on the IRS site anywhere. The [TIAA document](https://www.tiaa.org/public/pdf/pdf/your-guide-to-tax-deferred-annuities.pdf) makes multiple references to mandatory 403b contributions.

A financial advisor today told me that this situation would still count against the elective deferral limit ($18k in 2016) but I was skeptical and after looking further into the laws am even more skeptical.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain what is wrong with this question?

Comment: I'm curious: What are your other choices besides a 403(b)?

Comment: @BenMiller a defined benefit pension.

Answer (score -1):

So I learned that your employer CAN force you to make employee contributions. However, [this](http://benefitslink.com/boards/index.php/topic/37502-mandatory-deferrals/) source seems to think that the mandatory employee contributions do not count against the 402(g) limit of $18,000.

Comment: `Your employer can't force you to make deferral contributions` citation needed? I'm about 100% sure they do, particularly since my spouse's benefits plan __requires__ enrollment into a retirement plan. A few [other sources](https://www.bogleheads.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=156731) reference this and in fact, the [TIAA 403b overview uses the term 'mandatory'](https://www.tiaa.org/public/pdf/pdf/your-guide-to-tax-deferred-annuities.pdf). The TIAA document suggests my understanding is correct, however it is not the IRS documentation I am hoping to see.

Comment: I believe that this is one of the subtle differences between the 401(k) and the 403(b). An employer can require mandatory salary deduction contributions into a 403(b).

Comment: I was wrong. I did a little more digging and they can mandate employee contributions. I will edit my answer.